# Has System.Net.PeerToPeer been removed from .NET 4.5? C#

Tags: c#, namespaces

The namespace is not found in my Visual Studio 2017. I've been searching for answers, most of the posts are from 6+ years ago. But I've found nowhere saying it's no longer supported. Do I simply need to download it from somewhere else?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.peertopeer?view=netframework-4.7.1 it exists in the System.Net.dll assembly. Also, I don't know what you mean by namespace in Visual Studio. You need to reference the assembly that contains it in your project to make it available.

Comment: Sorry I may be using "namespace" wrong, but I need to require/import it. But it does not exist in VS 2017. How/from where do I download it?

Comment: Add a reference to the System.Net assembly from the project context menu. Alternately, you can install the System.Net nuget package.

Comment: Aluan is correct, .NET 4.5 requires a reference to System.Net to further expose those classes.

Comment: Okay, that's worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As documented on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.peertopeer?view=netframework-4.7.1), the members of that namespace reside in the System.Net assembly.

To make them available in your project, add a reference to `System.Net.dll` from the "Add Reference" context menu option of your `.csproj` in Visual Studio.

[image]

[image]

[image]